# Where does Hadoop fit in a N-tier architecture?

Tags: hadoop, database-design, architecture, hadoop2, bigdata

I am fairly new to  Hadoop and its eco-system. I am wondering where and how  does Hadoop fit in a typical N-Tier architecture or any modern day architecture ? Getting results from the Hadoop is superb, but how and which way can I marshall the data results to display them on  my presentation layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"typical n-tier system"?  Not "in" 2-tier client-server; not in 3-tier.

Map/reduce calculations of data can be added to any system.

Hadoop is map/reduce on a cluster with a distributed file system on redundant data.  It would put me in a mind of scheduled batch processing of data.

The way data would be delivered to Hadoop would either be real time or batch ETL process from transactional to reporting databases.

None of this is "typical".  Hadoop is relatively young - less than ten years old.